# What is a variably-sized type in the interior of a structure type

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to add an extra function in project nodogsplash.

```
struct addrlist_t {                                                    
        struct in_addr h_addr;
        struct addrlist_t *next;                                       
} *addrhead = NULL, *cur = NULL;
```

I am working in x86_64,  `sizeof(struct addrlist_t)` return 8 byte, I think here should be 16 byte.
The strange thing is  the pointer of `&cur->h_addr` and `&cur->next` are same.
Then i check `struct addrlist_t` in other program, it works fine.

gdb say:
Attempt to resolve a variably-sized type which appears in the interior of a structure type

Can anybody give me some help.

I check `gcc -E`

```
7812  struct hostent *he;                                                            
7813  struct addrlist_t {                                                            
7814   struct in_addr h_addr_list[0];                                                
7815   struct addrlist_t *next;                                                      
7816  } *addrhead = ((void *)0), *cur = ((void *)0);                                 
7817  struct addrlist_t **ppre = &addrhead;
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings at compile-time? Make sure you're compiling with `-Wall`. It seems like something is wrong with the definition of `struct in_addr`.

Comment: Could you include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: Maybe your `struct` is not what you say and has a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: You `addrlist_t` has a zero-sized array `h_addr_list` (it should be in last place), which is the precursor of [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: You should submit a patch upstream to properly use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) per [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error.

I use `gethostbyname` which include `#include <netdb.h>`:

```
       struct hostent {
           char  *h_name;            /* official name of host */
           char **h_aliases;         /* alias list */
           int    h_addrtype;        /* host address type */
           int    h_length;          /* length of address */
           char **h_addr_list;       /* list of addresses */
       }
       #define h_addr h_addr_list[0] /* for backward compatibility */
```

And `h_addr` is error defined.

Comment: [gethostbyname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) is *deprecated* (see its *`man`* page). You should **use [getaddrinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)**